# How to deep copy classes with traits mixed in

Tags: scala, traits, deep-copy

Here's some sample scala code.

```
abstract class A(val x: Any) {  
    abstract def copy(): A  
}  

class b(i: Int) extends A(i) {  
    override def copy() = new B(x)  
}  

class C(s: String) extends A(s) {  
    override def copy() = new C(x)  
}  

//here's the tricky part  
Trait t1 extends A {  
    var printCount = 0  

    def print = {  
        printCount = printCount + 1  
        println(x)  
    }  

    override def copy = ???  
}  

Trait t2 extends A {  
    var doubleCount = 0  

    def doubleIt = {  
        doubleCount = doubleCount + 1  
        x = x+x  
    }  

    override def copy = ???  
}  

val q1 = new C with T1 with T2  
val q2 = new B with T2 with T1
```

OK, as you've likely guessed, here's the question.
How can I implement copy methods in T1 and T2, such that weather they are mixed in with B, C, or t2/t1, I get a copy of the whole ball of wax?
for example, q2.copy should return a new B with T2 with T1, and q1.copy should return a new C with T1 with T2

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Compositionality of object construction

The basic problem here is, that, in Scala as well as in all other languages I know, object construction doesn't *compose*. Consider two abstract operations *op<sub>1</sub>* and *op<sub>2</sub>*, where *op<sub>1</sub>* makes property *p<sub>1</sub>* true and where *op<sub>2</sub>* makes property *p<sub>2</sub>* true. These operations are *composable* with respect to a *composition operation ○*, if *op<sub>1</sub> ○ op<sub>2</sub>* makes both *p<sub>1</sub>* and *p<sub>2</sub>* true. (Simplified, properties also need a composition operation, for example conjunction such as *and*.)

Let's consider the `new` operation and the property that `new A(): A`, that is, an object created by calling `new A` is of type `A`. The `new` operation lacks *compositionality*, because there is no operation/statement/function `f` in Scala that allows you to compose `new A` and `new B` such that `f(new A, new B): A with B`. (Simplified, don't think too hard about whether `A` and `B` must be classes or traits or interfaces or whatever).

### Composing with super-calls

Super-calls can often be used to compose operations. Consider the following example:

```
abstract class A { def op() {} }

class X extends A {
  var x: Int = 0
  override def op() { x += 1 }
}

trait T extends A {
  var y: String = "y"
  override def op() { super.op(); y += "y" }
}

val xt = new X with T
println(s"${xt.x}, ${xt.y}") // 0, y
xt.op()
println(s"${xt.x}, ${xt.y}") // 1, yy
```

Let `X.op`'s property be "`x` is increased by one" and let `T.op`'s property be "`y`'s length is increased by one". The composition achieved with the super-call fulfils both properties. Hooooray!

### Your problem

Let's assume that you are working with a class `A` which has a field `x`, a trait `T1` which has a field `y` and another trait `T2` which has a field `z`. What you want is the following:

```
val obj: A with T1 with T2
// update obj's fields
val objC: A with T1 with T2 = obj.copy()
assert(obj.x == objC.x && obj.y == objC.y && obj.z == objC.z)
```

Your problem can be divided into two compositionality-related sub-problems:

1. *Create* a new instance of the desired type. This should be achieved by a `construct` method.
2. *Initialise* the newly created object such that all its fields have the same values (for brevity, we'll only work with value-typed fields, not reference-typed ones) as the source object. This should be achieved by a `initialise` method.

The second problem can be solved via super-calls, the first cannot. We'll consider the easier problem (the second) first.

#### Object initialisation

Let's assume that the `construct` method works as desired and yields an object of the right type. Analogous to the composition of the `op` method in the initial example we could implement `initialise` such that each class/trait `A`, `T1` and `T2` implements `initialise(objC)` by setting the fields it knows about to the corresponding values from `this` (individual effects), and by calling `super.initialise(objC)` in order to compose these individual effects.

#### Object creation

As far as I can see, there is no way to compose object creation. If an instance of `A with T1 with T2` is to be created, then the statement `new A with T1 with T2` must be executed somewhere. If super-calls could help here, then something like

```
val a: A = new A // corresponds to the "deepest" super-call
val at1: A with T1 = a with new T1
```

would be necessary.

### Possible solutions

I implemented a solution ([see this gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5037918)) based on abstract type members and explicit mixin classes (`class AWithT1WithT2 extends A with T1 with T2;  val a = new AWithT1WithT2` instead of `val a = new A with T1 with T2`). It works and it is type-safe, but it is neither particularly nice nor concise. The explicit mixin classes are necessary, because the `construct` method of `new A with T1 with T2` must be able to name the type it creates.

Other, less type-safe solutions are probably possible, for example, casting via `asInstanceOf` or reflection. I haven't tried something along those lines, though.

Scala macros might also be an option, but I haven't used them yet and thus don't know enough about them. A compiler plugin might be another heavy-weight option.

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you! To bad this isn't legal, type self <: super.self with ...  That whole cyclic reference problem strikes again though.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

That is one of the reasons, why extending case classes is deprecated. You should get a compiler warning for that. How should the copy method, that is defined in `A`, know, that there may also be a `T` or whatever? By extending the case class,
you break all the assumptions, that the compiler made, when generating methods like `equals`, `copy` and `toString`.

Comment: Yes, exactly my thinking. It isn't logical to make a class a case class just for copying, that's not what they're for. If I was dealing with a class only, I could write a copy function, no prob. I just don't know how to do it with a trait mixed in. I hope someone does though.

Comment: If you want to take the trait into account, you have to implement the copy method in the trait (which will not work for multiple traits). Also instead ox extending the trait, you should give it a self type, eg: `trait T1 { this: A => }`, because extending a class from a trait has different behaviour, than just restricting the type you can mix-in the trait.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest and simplest answer is to make your concrete types into case classes. Then you get the compiler-supplied `copy` method which accepts named parameters for all the class's constructor parameters so you can selectively differentiate the new value from the original.

Comment: While this does copy the concrete class, it doesn't include the traits mixed in.

Comment: Of course it does. — Oh... You have state in your traits... Try to design that out.

Comment: Even a trait with no state, just a function, does not seem to copy for me.    case class A(val x: Int); trait T extends A {def say=println(x)}  Forgive the format